# SQL query takes time

Tags: database-administration

HI I have my application running on my production server perfectly, I updated the application some 2 days ago and since  then I experienced some performance related issue. The issue is  when  you click the button the query that runs against that button needs some 1 min or more to pull out the result and my application thus shows time out error but the same application runs fine here in my local.

I don't think its the issue related to query optimization since its  simple select query having joins  b/w 2 tables and its some 40-50 records pulled.

I am using SQL 2012 database, Is there any setting needs to be done on it?

Comment: How shall we help if you don't even say what sql server you use and what type of application, let alone your implementation of that "button" and the actual query and the database layout?

Comment: Duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49942/sql-query-takes-long-time for when it gets migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Could be anything dude, without having all the information. E.g. recent degraded disk on DB server, fragmented indexes, inefficient joins, inefficient query...

Here are some general tips...

- User Performance Monitor (PerfMon) to capture and review any long running queries
- DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174283.aspx

- DBCC INDEXDEFRAG

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms177571.aspx

- or more intrusive, rebuild indexes DBCC DBREINDEX

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181671.aspx

- Review the health of the database server, in particular harddrives where data and log files reside. Also, check server CPUs usages.